# What is this function called one()?

Tags: dataset, edit, apache-superset

I have 2 datasets which have been in use for about 2 years now with no problems.  I now need to add a new column to each dataset.  I have created the new column in each of the underlying tables.  The definition of the new column is identical in each table.

With one dataset there is no problem: Edit / COLUMNS / SYNC COLUMNS FROM SOURCE / SAVE does the job.

However, with the other dataset (which is based on a different table from the same database) everything is fine, i.e., SYNC COLUMNS finds the new column as expected, until I press SAVE.  I then get an error dialog:

---

### Error
No row was found for one()

Unsurprisingly, the new column has not been saved in the definition of the dataset even though it still appears in the list shown in the COLUMNS tab.

The underlying database is postgres.  There is no function called "one()" in postgres and neither can I find any mention of this function anywhere else.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.